# Periodic/Cyclic reminder

Tags: android, reminders

I'm trying to find an app that beeps every X minutes.

Just that. Beep once and begin counting another cycle.

The timer function of the alarm is not good, as I have to acknowledge the timer has ended.

I tried those "hourly chimes", but their period is not programmable (fixed to beep every hour)

I also tried those "water reminder" apps, but they're overcomplex and hardly programmable

Android Oreo

Thank you ahead.

Comment: Which OS is it for?

Comment: Oops. Android. Updated the thread.

Comment: Anyone ? Tried those "medicine reminders". Not useful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any automation app can do this easily. In Tasker it is very simple to set up to beep every x minutes. Set the profile to run on a time based on how many minutes you want. And set the task to alert/beep as needed.

```
    Profile: Beep Every 2 Min
    Time:  Every 2m



Enter Task: Anon

A1: Beep [
     Frequency: 8000
     Duration: 1000
     Amplitude: 50
     Stream: 3 ]
```

Comment: Very good. I had Tasker all along and didn't consider that ! Plus, it can be converted to an app via Tasker App Factory. I just didn't know how to import your code, so I created the task. The only problem is: this approach has a fixed timetable. Can't start the counter anytime I want. It's preprogrammed.

Comment: You can create the profile to start when you press a tasker shortcut or quick settings tile.